# jQuery iteration question (confused by example in a book)

Tags: jquery, iterator, toggle

I'm working my way through the O'Reilly *jQuery Cookbook*. On p. 100 there is an example where I don't get one detail. I'm in my first week of looking at jQuery, so that's no surprise, but I'm hoping someone can clarify.

The function is a toggle with a few bells & whistles:

`onValue` and `offValue` are both Booleans, and must have opposite senses, and it might have been clearer to have only one of them, but the idea is to accommodate something where (for example) `name` is "disable".
 the optional `on`, also a Boolean, lets caller use this as a "set" instead of a "toggle"

```
jQuery.fn.toggleAttr = function (name, onValue, offValue, on) {
    function set($element, on) {
        var value = on ? onValue : offValue;
        return value == null ? $element.removeAttr(name) : $element.attr(name, value);
    }
    return on !== undefined ?
        // next line is where I'm confused
        set(this, on) : 
        this.each(function (i, element) {
             var $element = $(element);
             set($element, $element.attr(name) !== onValue);
        });
};
```

How is `set( this, on )` working here? It seems to be working on the *list* of elements, but something needs to happen to *each* element, and I don't see what would cause any iteration. I'd have expected something more like the `on === undefined` case, something like:

```
        this.each (function( i, element ) {
            set( $(element), on);
        )}
```

So, am I missing something?

Comment: I'm guilty of not reading the code as closely as I should have, I deleted my answer.  I would now say you have not provided enough information.  How do you know that set gets applied to a list of elements?  In order for me to follow what is going on, I would need to see how the toggleAttr is applied.

Comment: I know that because `toggleAttr` is being defined as a method of jQuery.fn (hope that terminology is right, I'm a C++ developer, new to jQuery). This will be called in a context like:
`jQuery('ul#booklist li').toggleAttr("relevant", true, false, true);`
or
`jQuery('#workers li').toggleAttr("on-shift", true, false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `on` is not set then the toggleAttr function loops through each of the elements checking what the current value of the `name` attribute is set to and comparing that to the `onValue` variable.

When `on` IS set then that means you are telling toggleAttr "I want you to toggle all elements to true/false and ignore what the current value is". So it doesn't need to loop through all the elements and check what the current value is set to because you told it to brute force the value.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/sHJC3/2/

Comment: I think I see: so when `set` is passed a jQuery object, and that object is a list, `set` implicitly operates on the elements of the list, because `jQuery.fn.removeAttr` and `jQuery.fn.attr` implicitly operate on the elements of the list. Is that correct?

Comment: correct `jQuery.fn.removeAttr` and `jQuery.fn.attr` run on jQuery objects, doesn't matter if the jQuery object has 12 elements in the collection or 1.